# Stream from two dimensional array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to get an `IntStream` out of an n dimensional `int` arrays. Is there a nice API way to do it?
I know the concatenate method for two streams.

Comment: Would you add more details of the data you have, and how you want it delivered?

Comment: I just have a two dimensional int array. I don't think the solution is data dependent?

Comment: Do you want the `IntStream` to be iterating over each `int` in the `int[][]`?

Comment: The Arrays class in Java 8 has a public static <T> Stream<T> stream(T[] array) method. I guess that would do the trick. But I think an IntStream would only work for n=1.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Assuming you want to process array of array sequentially in row-major approach, this should work:

```
int[][] arr = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };
IntStream stream = Arrays.stream(arr).flatMapToInt(x -> Arrays.stream(x));
```

First it invokes the [`Arrays.stream(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) method, where `T` is inferred as `int[]`, to get a `Stream<int[]>`, and then [`Stream#flatMapToInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt-java.util.function.Function-) method maps each `int[]` element to an `IntStream` using [`Arrays.stream(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-) method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So it does give an `IntStream` traversing the array like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...`?

Comment: Yes. The `Function` given to `flatMapToInt` takes each element in the `int[][]`, ie. a single `int[]`, and constructs and returns a new `IntStream` for each. All of these are concatenated into one final `IntStream` which is returned. (Not exactly, but that's how you can think of it.)

Comment: This whole _functional_ thing is new to me :|

Answer (score 18):

To further expand on Rohit's answer, a method reference can be used to slightly shorten the amount of code required:

```
int[][] arr = { {1, 2, 3}, 
                {4, 5, 6},
                {7, 8, 9} };

IntStream stream = Arrays.stream(arr).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream);
```

Answer (score 2):

To process the elements only, use `flatMap` as in Rohit's answer.

To process the elements with their indices, you may use [`IntStream.range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) as follows.

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import static java.util.stream.IntStream.range;

public class StackOverflowTest {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int[][] arr = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
        // Map the two dimensional array with indices.
        final IntStream intStream = range(0, arr.length).flatMap(row -> range(0, arr[row].length).map(col -> {
            final int element = arr[row][col];
            // E.g. multiply elements in odd numbered rows and columns by two.
            return row % 2 == 1 || col % 2 == 1 ? element * 2 : element;
        }));
        // Prints "1 4 3 8 10 12 7 16 9 ".
        intStream.forEachOrdered(n -> System.out.print(n + " "));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the previous answers, the method `Arrays::stream` returns a sequential stream
(see: [Oracle Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T[]))). In some situations, a parallel stream might improve performance. To explicitly request a parallel stream, you first need to convert to a List via `Arrays::asList`, then call `parallelStream()` on the resulting List.

To calculate the sum of a two dimensional `int` array using a `IntStream`, you can use following code:

```
int[][] twoDimArray = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };
IntStream intStream = Arrays.asList(twoDimArray)
    .parallelStream()               // "rows" in parallel
    .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream);  // "columns" sequentially
int sum = intStream.sum();          // = 45
```

The Stream created for processing the outer layer (rows, first dimension) is now executing in parallel, while the Streams for the inner layer (columns, second dimension) are still sequential (using `Arrays::stream` mentioned above).

Depending on the size and structure of your array, you might see a performance increase by factor 4 (that's what I measured in my own tests) or none at all. If your calculations are time critical, it might be worth a try to use a parallel Stream.