# Counting specific characters in two dimensional array using stream

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I would like to count occurrences of a character (for example the space: `' '`
) in 2D Array, using stream. I was trying to find a solution. Here is my code, using a nested loops:

```
public int countFreeSpaces() {
    int freeSpaces = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (board[j][i] == ' ') freeSpaces++;
        }
    }
    return freeSpaces;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you tried with streams?

Comment: what type of array is board?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stream from two dimensional array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601036/stream-from-two-dimensional-array-in-java)

Comment: @Kh.Taheri 
Yes, I tried to implement it to my program, but can not do It because I have char array.

Comment: @CardinalSystem char Array

Comment: And this for char array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320910/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-java-8-stream-of-characters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this answer is slightly more expressive:

```
int freeSpaces = (int) Arrays.stream(board)
                             .map(CharBuffer::wrap)
                             .flatMapToInt(CharBuffer::chars)
                             .filter(i -> i == ' ')
                             .count();
```

Comment: Good approach, though I’d use `Arrays.stream` to stream over an existing array instead of the varargs method `Stream.of`. Also, `String::new` implies copying the `char[]` data, so I’d use `.map(CharBuffer::wrap) .flatMapToInt(CharSequence::chars)` instead. Contrary to what we might expect, in Java 8, `CharBuffer.chars()` is even implemented more efficient than `String.chars()`.

Comment: first, up-vote. due to I write down the answer I don't know the OP is whether using  a `char[]` or  a `Character[]`, so I used `IntStream` instead. as you can see my answer publish time is before the OP says its type is a `char[]`.

Comment: @Holger Thank you very much for your insight!  I'll change the answer around.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
//                      v--- create a Stream<char[]>             
int spaces = (int) Stream.of(board)
                          .flatMapToInt(cells->IntStream.range(0, cells.length)
                          .filter(i -> cells[i] == ' '))
                          .count();
```

Comment: :), why is wrong? I don't understand it. could anyone tell me why before I delete the answer? thanks. I'm not good at English.

Comment: That works fine, was expecting that it will be like shorter but it is easy to read.

Comment: @cerbin if you remove the comments and inline, you can find that will be shorter and expressive.

Comment: That is fine, these indentation increases readability. However, In my opinion these comments you made are not necessary, words from java like count() tells enough.

Comment: @cerbin okay. I'll remove the comments later.