# How can I optimize this nested for loop in java?

Tags: java

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < row ; i++){
        for (int k = 0 ; k < col ; k++) {
            System.out.print("\t" + mat[i][k]);
        }
```

> My objective is to reduce the execution time for a large value of rows and cols

Comment: The only optimization I can see is to print the tab and matrix element separately, to avoid the string concatenation. There is very little else that can be done.

Comment: Build an entire row with a `StringBuilder` and print once per row, instead of once per column.

Comment: please can you assist me on that @ Elliott Frisch

Comment: Andy, this was also my first impulse but I tested it with 1000*1000 integer numbers and redirected the output to /dev/null. Your suggested change makes no difference, which is a surprise to me as well.

Comment: Elliot, I tried your suggestion: it makes a big goof difference (1300ms versus 46ms). But this creates a big buffer in memory, why is it so much faster anyway?

Comment: I got like 10% improvement using a stream as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601036/stream-from-two-dimensional-array-in-java, but that's not close to what Elliot got.

Comment: @Stefan *why is it so much faster anyway?* `System.out` **blocks**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `System.out.println` takes time to execute. Currently in your code you are doing `System.out.println` for every element **we can reduce it to almost one fourth by doing `System.out.println` for each row instead of doing for each column**

**NOTE:**

Furthermore optimization can be done if you know beforehand how many rows and columns are there in your code. If there is a major difference in cardinality of rows and columns , then outer loop you can run with lower cardinality value.

You can see the below mentioned code :

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<row; i++) 
{

    for(int j=0; j<col; j++) 
    {
        sb.append('\t');    
        sb.append(mat[i][j]);
    }
    sb.append('\n');
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

I did not expect this but Elliot's comment is right. Bashir, you asked for an example, here it is:

```
public class Main
{

    private static void test()
    {
        int row = 1000;
        int col = 1000;
        int mat[][] = new int[row][col];

        StringBuilder buffer=new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < col; k++)
            {
                //System.out.print("\t" + mat[i][k]);

                //System.out.print('\t');                
                //System.out.print(mat[i][k]);

                buffer.append('\t');
                buffer.append(mat[i][k]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        test();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.err.println("Test took " + (end - start) + "ms");
    }
}
```

I executed it (on Linux) at the command-line to ensure that the performance of my terminal window or graphic card does not affect the measurement:

```
java Main > /dev/null
```

The buffered version runs 30x faster than the original.

Comment: You need to reset the `buffer` after each row. Oh, you did the entire contents in one shot. Fair enough.

Comment: Yes, I did not care how much memory this takes. I wanted to "prove" that you suggestion is false and very slow, but I failed grandious :-)

Comment: thank you it really helped although I used the code below and I code 
Test took 1347ms

Answer (score 0):

If you just intend to print your 2-D array, you can use `Arrays.deepToString`. However, you intend to print it in the format you have mentioned and still want to reduce the I/O operations, you can build a string using `StringBuilder` and print it. Note that both these options will cost you memory. The first option internally uses `StringBuilder` while in the second option, you will be building the string yourself using the `StringBuilder`. So, it's the number of I/O operations vs. memory utilization.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] mat = { { 10, 20 }, { 40, 30 } };

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mat));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < mat[0].length; k++) {
                sb.append("\t" + mat[i][k]);
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[10, 20], [40, 30]]
    10  20
    40  30
```