# get a 2d array of doubles in a custom Object in a Map

Tags: java

I have a custom object in a Map: below is the structure

```
Allocation {
double risk;
double[] weights;
double returnValue;
}
```

I have a Map of Allocation Objects such as:

```
Map<String, Allocation>
```

I would like to get the weights in a 2d array with Java 8.

weights={{.3, .2, 0.5}, {0.4, 0.4,0.2}, {0.5, 0.25, 0.25},...}

The Allocation Map contains many Portfolio objects like below:

```
key: portfolio1, Object: (risk=0.03, weights={0.3,0.2,0.5}, returnvalue=0.5)
Key: portfolio2, Object: (risk=0.05, weights={0.4,0.4,0.2}, returnvalue=0.3)
Key: portfolio3, Object: (risk=0.01, weights={0.5, 0.25, 0.25}, return=0.6)
```

I would like to get an 2d array of weights:

```
weights[0] = {0.3,0.2,0.5}
weights[1] = {0.4,0.4,0.2}
weights[1] = {0.5, 0.25, 0.25} and so on...
```

Looking for the best way to do so
Thanks!

Comment: Your weights field only shows a single d array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stream from two dimensional array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601036/stream-from-two-dimensional-array-in-java)

Comment: Updated the question to be more clear as to what I am looking for. @nabster, I checked the link but does not solve my issue. I am essentially trying to retrieve the weights, which is an array inside of a custom object. I would like to get the weights for all the Allocation objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `map` on the values:

```
double[][] weights = 
    map.values()               
       .stream()
       .map(Allocation::getWeights)
       .toArray(double[][]::new);
```

[Link to online tester](https://ideone.com/kyHkfm)

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this.

```
    Map<String, Allocation> map = new HashMap<>();
    Allocation a = new Allocation();
    a.weights = new double[]{10.0,12.0};
    Allocation b = new Allocation();
    b.weights = new double[]{20.0,32.0};
    map.put("A",a);
    map.put("B",b);
    double weights[][] = map.values()
                .stream()
                .map(obj->obj.weights)
                .toArray(double[][]::new);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(weights));
```

Prints

```
[[10.0, 12.0], [20.0, 32.0]]
```

Note, since your `Allocation` class did not have getters, I used `obj->obj.weights` rather than `Allocation::getWeights` in my solution to match your class as defined.

Comment: thanks! I do have getters but did not show here. But this works. Thank you